# Detect partial string matches in R

Tags: r, regex, optimization, string-matching

I am trying to count the number of transactions which start with *AK* and also contain *AK* within the transaction, but don't end in *AK*.

Examples:

***EXCLUDE***:
example: AK->se (no AK in between)

***EXCLUDE***: AK->gg->se->ll : does not include *AK* within the transaction

***INCLUDE:***
example:
AK->se->Ak->gg

**Sample data:**

```
f<- data.frame(
id=c("A","A","A","A","C","C","D","D","E"),
Mode=c("AK->se","se->AK->gg, bishan->K","AK->se","se->gr->gg, bishan->AK","AK->se","se->gr->gg, bishan->AK","AK->se","se->gr->gg, bishan->AK","se->AK->df, hg->pp->sk")
)
```

*I need to deal with a large amount of data so optimization is crucial.*

Thanks in advance.

**Edited**

```
f<- data.frame(
id=c("A","A","A","A","C","C","D","D","E"),
Mode=c("AK->se","se->AK->gg, bishan->K","AK->se","se->gr->gg, bishan->AK","AK->se","AK->AK->gg, bishan->AK","AK->se->Ak->gg","se->gr->gg, bishan->AK","AK->AK->df, hg->pp->sk")
)
```

Comment: you might want to rephrase your question. "I am trying get the count on the number of the transation. I want the transaction start with AK and in within the transaction contain AK but it does not end with AK." is not very clear

Comment: Rephrased it for the OP for clarity.

Comment: I don't understand the second element "se->AK->gg, bishan->K". You need to explain better the format of the transactions

Comment: Do you have access to the 'un-concatenated' data, i.e. something like this (for ID A): `df <- data.frame(id = rep("A", 7), grp = c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 2)), time = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2), state = c("AK", "se", "se", "AK", "gg", "bishan", "K"))`? If so, you may use other (more convenient, I think) techniques to categorize the transactions. Just a thought.

Comment: I don't understand. what is id, grp, time? we need either a simpler dataset or more explanation. what is a transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using regular expression

```
f<- data.frame(
  id=c("A","A","A","A","C","C","D","D","E"),
  Mode=c("AK->se","se->AK->gg, bishan->K","AK->se","se->gr->gg, bishan->AK","AK->se","se->gr->gg, bishan->AK","AK->se->AK->gg","se->gr->gg, bishan->AK","se->AK->df, hg->pp->sk")
)

selection = grepl(pattern="^AK->.*AK->",x=f$Mode,perl=TRUE)
f$Mode[selection]
f$id[selection]
```

using lapply (might be a bit slower if there is a lot of strings)

```
f<- data.frame(
  id=c("A","A","A","A","C","C","D","D","E"),
  Mode=c("AK->se","se->AK->gg, bishan->K","AK->se","se->gr->gg, bishan->AK","AK->se","se->gr->gg, bishan->AK","AK->se->AK->gg","se->gr->gg, bishan->AK","se->AK->df, hg->pp->sk")
)

selection = sapply(strsplit(x=f$Mode,split="->"),FUN=function(x) (x[1]=="AK")&(x[length(x)]!="AK")&(sum(x=="AK")>1))
f$Mode[selection]
f$id[selection]
```

Comment: The lapply still select the transaction which end with AK. Would you mind to try with the data inside edited portion?

Comment: @Carol I think that there are missing " in the data inside the edited portion of your post.

Comment: Thanks I solved it already! But then allow to me to ask one more question: How would the regression REGEX be if I want the opposite pattern?

Comment: on the right of this page, you should have a section called "Related". Check the first item!

Comment: Sorry to say that, but I don't really get what you mean :(